# How to call a method from the View? MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a View with a `<input type="submit" value="Create" />` when a User click create the Action Method should be activated and the Result written in the db.

At the moment when a User click Create Button in the View nothing happen. Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong? thanks

```
using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using TestGuestBook.Models;
using TestGuestBook.Models.Repositories;
using TestGuestBook.ViewModels;

namespace TestGuestBook.Controllers
{
    [HandleError]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        ICommentRepository _repository;

        public HomeController()
        {
            _repository = new CommentRepository();
        }

        // Dependency Injection enabled constructors
        public HomeController(ICommentRepository repository)
        {
            _repository = repository;
        }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            // Get all Comments
            List<Comment> commentItems = _repository.FindAll().ToList();
            // Create the ViewModel and associate the list of comments
            CommentListCreateViewModel viewModel = new CommentListCreateViewModel();
            viewModel.CommentItems = commentItems;

            return View(viewModel);
        }

        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            CommentListCreateViewModel createViewModel = new CommentListCreateViewModel();
            return View(createViewModel);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(CommentListCreateViewModel createViewModel)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                Comment comment = new Comment
                {
                    Nominative = createViewModel.Nominative,
                    Email = createViewModel.Email,
                    Content = createViewModel.Content
                };
                _repository.Add(comment);
                _repository.Save();
            }
            return View();
        }

    }
}
```

---

View

```
@model TestGuestBook.ViewModels.CommentListCreateViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<h2>
    Index</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>ListAddCommentsViewModel</legend>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nominative)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Nominative)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nominative)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Content)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Content)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Content)
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Nominative
        </th>
        <th>
            Email
        </th>
        <th>
            Content
        </th>
        <th>
        </th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model.CommentItems)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nominative)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Content)
            </td>
            <td>
            </td>
        </tr>

    }
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to direct the form to your `Create` controller method:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Home"))
```

Comment: Replace the line `@using (Html.BeginForm())` with what I posted.  Without specifying the Action in the form, it will post back to the same URL, and it will simply call the Index action.

Comment: I did and now I receive an error The view 'Create' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched: ... I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong here. I need to post on the same URL

Comment: my idea is to display a list of item and the web form for creating new one on the same page

Comment: It's calling the `Create` method and trying to display the Create view, which must not exist.  In your `Create` HttpPost method, you can change the method to show the Index view: `return View("Index");`

Answer (score 0):

You can leave it as Html.BeginForm() and after the save, call return RedirectToAction("Index");  The added item should now show in the list. It was probably saving all along, it just wasn't being re-directed to the Index view afterwards.

Comment: The form is posting to Index so leaving `BeginForm` alone won't work.

Comment: Ah, I missed that this is the Index view and not the create view. :-)